# How can I create a geometrical texture on a section of an STL file?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

I have an already existing STL file of a car headlight but I want to add a specific raised geometrical texture, not just a PNG image but an actual texture that can be felt when it is 3-D printed. Anybody here know how this can be done?

I want the raised texture to be applied in specific places that I choose. It is a grid pattern that can be felt dipping up and down by 1mm.

Looking forward to your replies!

[image: Side view of light with texture]

[image: stl screenshot]

Comment: Would you be able to post an image representative of the destination model and of the texture to be applied? Is the source already an STL or do you require that to be created?

Comment: Just edited the post to show the pictures. The STL is already created. Just need the raised texture on the three sections you see in the photo. It has to wrap around each side following the curvature of the model.

Comment: currently, FDM printed replacement parts are not allowed for light covers in many countries.